# Least upper bound of $A*B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets of positive real numbers. Suppose $$A*B = [ab \mid a \in A \text{ and } b \in B].$$ Then $$\operatorname{lub}(A*B) = \operatorname{lub}(A)*\operatorname{lub}(B).$$

I think this is true, but I'm not sure how to prove it, and have been trying it for a while now. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Answser might be here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46738/product-of-sets-and-supremum

Comment: "lub" is is typically written as "sup" for supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ we have $ab\leq\text{lub}\left(A\right)\times\text{lub}\left(B\right)$ showing
that $\text{lub}\left(A\right)\times\text{lub}\left(B\right)$ is
an upper bound of $A\star B$.

This allows the conclusion $\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)\leq\text{lub}\left(A\right)\times\text{lub}\left(B\right)$.

---

Now assume that $\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)<\text{lub}\left(A\right)\times\text{lub}\left(B\right)$.

Then elements $x,y$ can be found with: $$x<\text{lub}\left(A\right)\wedge y<\text{lub}\left(B\right)\wedge\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)<xy$$

Here $x$ is no upperbound of $A$ and $y$ is no upperbound of $B$
so we can find elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $x<a\wedge y<b$
and consequently $\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)<ab$.

This contradicts that $\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)$ is an upper bound of $A\star B$ so the assumption $\text{lub}\left(A\star B\right)<\text{lub}\left(A\right)\times\text{lub}\left(B\right)$
must be false.

Answer (score 0):

For $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ $ab \leq sup(A) * sup(B) $, hence $sup(A*B) \leq sup(A) * sup(B) $.

Suppose $sup(A*B) < sup(A) * sup(B) $ we define $\epsilon := $sup(A) * sup(B) - sup(A*B) $

$\epsilon > 0$

We can choose  and $a_1 \in A$ such that $sup(A) - a_1  < \sqrt{\epsilon} $ 
and $b_1 \in B$ such that $sup(B) - b_1  < \sqrt{\epsilon} $

We get $a_1 b_1 < sup(A*B) $ and $sup(A)*sup(B) - a_1 b_1 < \sqrt{\epsilon} \sqrt{\epsilon} = \epsilon $.  Contradiction.