# How do you prove each $x$ for $a^x=y$ is unique?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not looking for limits or any calculus-related argument, I want to know how to ***prove uniqueness*** on a more fundamental level. I am at the point where I want to show $$a^x=a^y \implies x=y$$ but if I haven't yet proven the existence of a logarithm, how could it possibly be possible to show that $x=y$ ?

There is no way to get rid of that base $a$, but the fact that someone has already defined $\log_a(x)$ implies someone somehow did so some centuries ago.

In other uniqueness arguments like of rational functions, you can manipulate both sides with rational operations, but you can't do that here because you haven't proven a logarithm yet! So **how could anyone possibly show $x=y$ for $x>0$, $y>0$**.

Unless, can I use the properties of a logarithm after only making an argument for the existence of $x$ such that $a^{x}=y$ even if I haven't yet proven uniqueness and then use the existence to prove uniqueness for $a \neq 1$?

Comment: How do you define $a^x$ without the natural logarithm?

Comment: Note:  $a^x$ strictly increases with $x$

Comment: Through its properties, that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, etc. You can't just assume an inverse element exist, because if you did, then the set of only positive integers would be a field, but it isn't because it has no inverse operation. Just like with other inverse operations, you have to prove each $x$ in $a^{x}=y$ also exists, not just the $y$.

Comment: So how do you define the exponential in the first place?

Comment: Since $a^x$ and $log_a(x)$ are the two faces of the same coin, it is crucial here to express clearly what you use as definitions and what should be proved. Also, $a^x$ for $x$ a real number, is a calculus object by nature, so it is difficult (and probably impossible) to get a proof with no "calculus-related argument".

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: only when $a>1$. Consider $a=\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Comment: It's definitely possible, you can use other analytic tools. Take a look at this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Logarithm. The last line is where I am stuck on. I don't see how they can assume their last conclusion without already assuming the thing they are trying to prove is true in the first place.

Comment: @askmathquestions: it depends where you put the frontier between calculus and analysis. Anyway, your link does not define $b^x$.

Comment: I guess you mean for $a\ne1$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner: nope, I meant $a>1$. The function $f(x)=a^x$ is increasing for $a>1$, decreasing for $0<a<1$ and constant for $a=1$. What is important for the definition of $\log_a$ is that $f$ is monotonic, hence one-to-one, when $a\neq 1$. And that's why there is no logarithm in base $1$.

Comment: I know that;  I meant OP means $a\ne1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I get it. You are right.

Comment: It doesn't define $b^x$, but since it takes advantage of the exponential's functional properties, and there is no calculus defined within the argument, then I can only think it has to be defined by its functional properties.

Comment: So in the preceding arguments, they have proven the "existence" of the logarithm, but not yet the uniqueness, is that right? Because existence $\neq$ uniqueness, so if they have shown that the logarithm exists, can you use the logarithm itself to prove the uniqueness of its own mapping?

Comment: The “functional properties” that you provide do not suffice to conclude that the function has an inverse or is one-to-one. You need more. Usually, you need continuity (calculus), measurability (measure theory/calculus), semi-continuity (calculus), or other concepts. The property $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ is insufficient, even when you add $f(1)=a$, $f(0)=1$. What is the complete list of “functional properties” you want to specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the real analysis tag, I'll assume we're dealing with $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In order to prove something about the function $x \mapsto a^x$, we must know what $a^x$ means. I'll try to do this without invoking calculus concepts or defining a logarithm by taking an approach suggested by Arturo Magidin. Let's build up our notion of exponentiation.

First, if $x$ is constrained to the positive integers (I'll denote it by $x=n$), we *define* $a^n$ by $a*a* ...*a$, with $n$ repetitions of multiplication. If $x$ is a negative integer, we *define* $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$. Injectivity of the map $n \mapsto a^n$ is clear by strict monotonicity for $a \neq 1$ (the map is even more obviously not injective for $a = 1$).

If $x$ is constrained to the rational numbers (I'll denote it by $x = q = \frac{n}{m}$ with $m$ positive), we must establish that for each $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ we may find a unique $b \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $b^m$ = $a$. Once this is done, we may *define* $a^q = b^n$. It's easy to see that this is independent of the representation of $q$ as a ratio of integers. A straightforward way to observe the unique existence of such a $b$ is to consider that the map $y \mapsto y^m$ is continuous and monotone on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, that $0^m =0$, and that $\lim_{y \to \infty} y^m = \infty$, so the intermediate value theorem gives existence and monotonicity gives uniqueness. By expressing any $q_1 = \frac{n_1}{m}$, $q_2 = \frac{n_2}{m}$ with a common denominator, we easily deduce strict monotonicity (and hence injectivity) of $q \mapsto a^q$ from the integer result.

Now, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is unconstrained and $a>1$, we consider the set $W^x_a := \{a^w : w \in \mathbb{Q}, w \leq x \}$. Recalling that $q \mapsto a^q$ for $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ is strictly increasing, we see that $W_a^x$ has an upper bound given by $a^q$ for any $q > x$, so its supremum exists (it is certainly nonempty). Thus, we may *define* $a^x = \sup (W_a^x)$. Now, if $x < y \in \mathbb{R}$, we may find $q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x<q_1<q_2<y$, and hence for any rational $w \leq x$ we have $a^w <a^{q_1}$, showing $a^{q_1}$ is an upper bound for $W_a^x$, so $a^x \leq a^{q_1} < a^{q_2} \leq a^y$ (since $a^{q_2} \in W_a^y$). This shows that $x \mapsto a^x$, according to this definition, is strictly monotone and hence injective, as desired.

In the case $0<a<1$, one must take the infimum instead of the supremum and reverse some inequalities, but the result is the same.

**Comments:** This definition, while having the advantage of being relatively elementary, is a bit unwieldy. Indeed, I expect it would be annoying to prove results such as surjectivity onto $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, the continuity of either $x \mapsto a^x$ or $a \mapsto a^x$, or the identity $(a^{x})^y = a^{xy}$, whereas these are nearly immediate in the standard approach of defining $a^x = \exp(x\ln(a))$ (once one has done the work of defining $\exp$ and $\ln$). Further, this definition doesn't lend itself at all to generalizing our considerations to complex numbers (or $a<0$). However, we can at least get 
$$a^{x}a^{y} = \sup(W_a^x) * \sup(W_a^y) = \sup(W_a^x W_a^y) = \sup(W_a^{x+y}) = a^{x+y}$$
(see [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46738/355036)) without much trouble. It's not difficult at all to show that this agrees with the definition given in the standard approach using the latter's continuity.

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing about logarithms, the question need not even begin to make sense, since it is unclear just what $a^x$ might mean, even for positive $a$, when $x$ is not restricted.

You say in the comments that you would define the function $f(x)=a^x$ simply as a function with the property that
$$\begin{align*}
f(1) &= a\\
f(x+y) &= f(x)f(y).
\end{align*}$$

However, these properties do **not** suffice to conclude that $f$ is one-to-one (which is required in order to conclude that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$), or that there is a unique $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ for a given $y$ (or at most one such $x$ if you don't want to assume surjectivity).

In particular, if we assume the Axiom of Choice, then there are functions that satisfy both $f(1)=a$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$, but that are *not* one to one.

"Explicitly" (modulo the Axiom of Choice), let $\beta$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $1\in\beta$. Then any function $g\colon \beta\to\mathbb{R}$ can be extended to an additive function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$; that is, a function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, whose values at $\beta$ are as specified, and such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$.

Now, define $g\colon \beta\to\mathbb{R}$ by letting $g(1) = 1$ and $g(r)=0$ for all $r\in\beta$, $r\neq 1$. Then define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = a^{g(x)}$.

Then $f(1) = a^{g(1)} = a^1= a$; and $f(x+y) = a^{g(x+y)} = a^{g(x)+g(y)} = a^{g(x)}a^{g(y)} = f(x)f(y)$. So this function $f$ satisfies the two given equations.

However, $\beta$ is uncountable, so pick $r\neq 1$ that is in $\beta$. Then $f(r) = a^{g(r)} = a^0 = 1$, and $f(0) = 1$ (since $g(0)=0$ must hold for $g$ to be additive). However, $r\neq 0$, since $0$ cannot be an element of $\beta$.

Thus, the two conditions $f(1)=a$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ do not suffice to show that $f$ is one-to-one.

Which means you need to specify a lot of other stuff; specifically, one need to know *exactly* what properties you are giving the function $f$.

(Yes, I know I'm using the exponential function to define this; but the point is that there are interpretations of the function $f$ that make all the assumptions true but the desired conclusion false, which means that one cannot prove the fact that $f$ is one-to-one using *only* the assumptions listed)

---

It is difficult to define either the exponential or the logarithm at the basic level of calculus-before-the-fundamental-theorem.

One can define the exponential function by first defining the functions $a\longmapsto a^n$ with $n$ a positive integer, inductively. Then for $n$ a negative integer using reciprocals. Then for $n$ the reciprocal of a positive integer using inverse functions. Then for $n$ a rational using $a^{p/q} = (a^p)^{1/q}$. Then prove that if $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{r}{s}$ with $p,q,r,s$ integers, $r,s\gt 0$, then we get $a^{p/q}=a^{r/s}$. Then define $a^x$ for arbitrary $x$ by letting $(q_n)$  be a sequence of rationals such that $q_n\to x$ as $n\to\infty$, and showing that the sequence $a^{q_n}$ is Cauchy and converges to a number we call $a^x$. Then showing that if $(q_n)$ and $(r_n)$ are two sequences of rationals that both converge to $x$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{q_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} a^{r_n}$. And once all of this has been done, then one can show that the function is stricitly monotone when $a\gt 0$, $a\neq 1$, to deduce what you want (and hence that it has an inverse and logarithms exist).

Obviously, this requires a lot of work.

Or one can use integrals and define the natural logarithm by
$$\ln(x)  = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$$
for $x\gt 0$. Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus one can show that this function is continuous and differentiable; using the properties of the integral that it is strictly increasing, and so has an inverse. Call the inverse the exponential function $\exp(x)$; and then define $a^x = \exp(x\ln(a))$. And then prove that this function is strictly monotone when $a\gt 0$, $a\neq 1$.

This requires enough Calculus to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus first. Again, a lot of work.

---

"Someone did it centuries ago"... The logarithm is a pretty recent "invention" as these things go, and it is closely connected with the development of calculus. Actual formal proofs of its properties (as well as actual formal proofs of the properties of the general exponential function) date from after the invention of calculus, and generally require some analysis or some calculus. I don't think you can really prove this via "elementary", non-analysis, non-calculus methods.

Comment: It's already proven via non-calculus, though not necessarily non-analysis methods. You're not supposed to be able to assume it's 1-1 right away, that is a correct problem to point out, it would need to be proven more analytically, hence the point of going through its proof.

Comment: @askmathquestions He did not assume it was 1-1 "right away". By the Cauchy sequence approach or via the integral approach, the next step is to prove monotonicity. The Cauchy sequence approach uses simple properties of limits to do this; the integral approach uses that the $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$ is strictly increasing with $x$ because the integrand is strictly positive. This implies its inverse function, $\exp$, is also strictly monotone. In the integral approach, one also needs to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln(x) = -\infty$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(x) = \infty$.

Comment: I think that is a useful type of proof to have in mind. However, you will not always have nice differential properties for a given function upon which to construct such an argument.

Comment: @askmathquestions Indeed. However, the function asked about does. Regardless, the actual proof of your result didn't have anything to do with any "differential properties"-- it's just monotonicity. The bulk of this answer is establishing what exactly one means by $a^x$, which one must know in order to prove it is monotone. The standard construction of this particular function just happens to involve calculus, but notice that the first construction given didn't use calculus at all.

Comment: @askmathquestions: I do not understand the point of your comments. “It’s already proven via non-calculus”. By who? How? All methods I know if **actually** proving properties of the exponential functions involve at least limits, which I classify as “calculus.” And while exponential functions were used before calculus, not arbitrary ones, or at least not formally enough to talk proving its properties.

Comment: @askmathquestions: let me also note that just because you want a proof that doesn’t use `X` does not mean that such a proof exists. And if you want a proof, then you need to specify what you are willing to allow to be used a priori, and what you need proving. For instance, do you allow the fact that Cauchy sequences have limits? Etc.

Comment: A non-calculus proof already exists, there's no reason to be instinctively against the idea.

Comment: @askmathquestions: What exactly do you mean by "a non-calculus proof already exists"? What proof? Where? What does it use? There's nothing "instinctive" here; I said: if you want a proof that avoids something common, then you need to **specify** what you allow and what you do not.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I believe OP may be referring to the result at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Logarithm#Proof , which OP linked to in the comments. However, the argument there implicitly assumed strict monotonicity of $x \mapsto a^x$ (they use it in their proof of existence), so it essentially neglected the entire issue of injectivity by assuming the result. It does not give a self-contained "non-calculus" proof of injectivity.

Comment: @jawheele: Thank you; all sufficiently solid definitions of the exponential function that I know either use limits (by defining it as the limit of $a^{q_n}$ with $(q_n)\to x$ a sequence of rationals; or as the limit of an infinite series), or integrals (via logarithms). I guess one *could* define $a^x$ for positive $x$ as the supremum of $a^{q}$ with $q$ rational, $0\leq q\leq x$, but I suspect that actually proving the relevant properties then would be rather difficult without resorting to limits at some point.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The definition you suggest actually seems to suffice quite well to give OP's result without any critical use of limits or calculus (assuming you don't consider the intermediate value theorem calculus, which I don't). I've posted an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

$a^x$ is increasing for $a > 1$ and decreasing for $0 < a < 1$.

If $a^x = a^y$ then,
if you have the usual properties of power,
$a^{x-y} = 1$.

If $a^{x-y} = 1$ and $x \ne y$
then
$a^{n(x-y)} = 1$
for all integral $n$.

It all depends on what you know
about the $a^x$ function.

Comment: Well, I know at least that it's functional properties are accepted in this argument. I think you mean "integer" $n$ when you said "integral" $n$.

Comment: @askmathquestions: "$n$ integral" and "integral $n$" are correct alternative ways of saying "$n$ is an integer"; though in the context of calculus it might be confusing to use those particular turns of phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You touch on a very important problem regarding the mathematical concept of *functions*. Your question of whether $a^x=a^y$ implies $x=y$ is a special case of the more general question of whether $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$, for a certain function $f$. We have the following important definition:

> A function $f$ taking real arguments is called *injective* if $f(a)=f(b)$ for real numbers $a$ and $b$ implies that $a=b$.

This definition extends to functions of complex numbers, as well as functions over arbitrary sets as well, but let's not worry about that for now. Indeed, if a function $f$ is injective, then we can define an *inverse function* $f^{-1}$ by $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$ for all real numbers $a$.

Our question of whether $a^x=a^y$ implies $x=y$ now comes down to the question of whether $f(x)=a^x$ is an injective function. For $a>0$ with $a\neq1$, the answer is **yes**. An easy way to convince yourself of this is by drawing the graph. For a sufficiently nice injective function $f$, drawing the graph $y=f(x)$ will reveal that every line parallel to the $x$-axis will intersect the graph at at most one point. This is because every such line is of the form $y=b$ for a constant $b$, and $b=f(x)$ implies $x=f^{-1}(b)$, which is a unique value. This is known as the *[horizontal line test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_line_test)*. Now if we draw the graph considering the two cases where $0<a<1$ and where $a>1$, and then apply the horizontal line test, you should be able to see easily that $f$ is indeed injective.

---

**Note:** The so-called horizontal line test is not really rigorous at all. A more rigorous way of showing that $f$ is injective is by showing that it is strictly monotonic; that is, $x>y$ implies $a^x>a^y$. This is what Miguel Boto and marty cohen's answers do.

Comment: But let's say you don't have fancy computer algorithms that you nicely graph the function. Then what do you do?

Answer (score 0):

$$a^x = a^y ⇒ a^x * \frac{1}{a^y} = 1 ⇒ a^{x-y} = 1 ⇒ a^{x-y} = a^0 ⇒ x-y = 0 ⇒ x = y$$

This is true only if a ≠ o and a ≠ 1. 
If a = 1, then x ≠ y.
If a = 0, then $$a^{x-y} ≠ 1$$

Comment: You assume injectivity when you make the step $a^{x-y} =a^0 \implies x-y = 0$.

Comment: For any a ≠ 0 and ≠ 1, x = y because the difference of only equal numbers can lead to a value of 0.

Comment: You could more simply specify those constraints with $x>1, y>1$ for convenience.

Comment: x and y can equal 0 or 1, as well as negative numbers. a can also equal negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Exponential functions are $1-1$.

Therefore, $a^{x} = a^{y}$ if and only if $x = y$.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to give a simple explanation.Let us consider a^x=a^y.
Which means a*a*a*-----(x times) = a*a*a*------- (y times).
It means a*a*   (x times)/a*a*  (y times) =1.
This is possible only when both numerator and denominator has same number of terms.
Which yields x=y.

Comment: But how do you *know* it's only possible when x=y? Uniqueness is the thing you're trying to prove, but it looks like you're assuming uniqueness is true in order to prove it's true!

Comment: What does it mean to multiply $a$ by itself $\frac{7}{3}$ times? What about $\pi$ times?

Comment: What is $a\times a\times\dots\times a$  $(-\pi)$ times? What are denominators and numerators here?

Comment: No,your aryuement of unique ness does not exist only in case of 1,0.Else every where this exist.

Comment: You could prove a unique upper bound for the convergence of a series representation of $\pi$ using the functional properties of an exponential, i.e. for  a set of rational numbers $Q$, that $a^{q_{1}}a^{q_{2}}a^{q_{3}}...$ converges to a transcendental number.

Comment: @magidin it is a^1/3 * a^1/3 * so on seven times .

Comment: @ArturoMagidin $x^{\pi}$ is $x$ times itself three times then times... er... a little extra bit of $x$. :)

Comment: @askmathquestions That is a possibility, but it would be extremely tedious to consider all the details. For example, why is it obvious that the limit of the sequence $a^{q_1},a^{q_2},...$ is independent of the choice of sequence of rationals $q_1,q_2,...$ converging to $\pi$?

Comment: @jawheele limits are a specific construct used to define the condition of continuity for the purposes of calculus that use upper and lower bounds. If you actually want to prove a limit from a fundamental level, then it's even more tedious. An infimum/supremum is like a precursor to a limit.

Comment: @mechanics: You miss the point. Your argument is only valid when $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. Otherwise, exponentiation is not defined in terms of multiplying something by itself. In particular, you don't even say what $a^{1/3}$ means. Does it mean multiplying $a$ by itself $\frac{1}{3}$-times? How do you do something one third of a time?

Comment: That's fine, I am only concerned with positive real numbers.

Comment: If you want it to be in the question so badly, then you need to ask for it to be done. The comments are not a red anything, the whole point of this question is to address uniqueness on a fundamental level like on the wiki page, without calculus, without limits, without derivatives, etc using the conventional $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ argument.

Comment: What I would like to convey is that x might be a fraction but hi can write a fraction as x/y.Which mean 1/y x times.Here we are worried only about the powers.What if I prove it for a^1/y

Comment: @askmathquestions The question needs to contain all the relevant information; otherwise, you are misleading your readers. It is not up to the people you are asking favors from to request that you provide the necessary information to do the favor for you.